# Openai chatbot to answer user's questions based on a csv file

Tags: dataframe, csv, openai-api, langchain, azure-openai

I'm trying to build an app using reflex, which uses openai to answer user's question based on an uploaded csv file.
I use Azure openai models as a LLM (I have gpt-4 and gpt-35-turbo-16k there).
I got a 'resource not found' error, and now i get this:

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\reflex\state.py", line 1032, in _process_event
    yield state._as_state_update(handler, next(events), final=False)
  File "C:...\Dataframe_Chatbot\state.py", line 110, in answer
    output = agent.run(self.question)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 505, in run
    return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 310, in __call__
    raise e
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 304, in __call__
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1146, in _call
    next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 933, in _take_next_step
    output = self.agent.plan(
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\openai_functions_agent\base.py", line 104, in plan
    predicted_message = self.llm.predict_messages(
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 650, in predict_messages
    return self(messages, stop=_stop, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 600, in __call__
    generation = self.generate(
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 349, in generate
    raise e
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 339, in generate
    self._generate_with_cache(
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 492, in _generate_with_cache
    return self._generate(
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\openai.py", line 360, in _generate
    response = self.completion_with_retry(
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\openai.py", line 299, in completion_with_retry
    return _completion_with_retry(**kwargs)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 289, in wrapped_f
    return self(f, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 379, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 314, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 451, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 382, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\openai.py", line 297, in _completion_with_retry
    return self.client.create(**kwargs)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\chat_completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py", line 151, in create
    ) = cls.__prepare_create_request(
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py", line 85, in __prepare_create_request       
    raise error.InvalidRequestError(
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: Must provide an 'engine' or 'deployment_id' parameter to create a <class 'openai.api_resources.chat_completion.ChatCompletion'>
```

This is my code:

```
import reflex as rx
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_experimental.agents.agent_toolkits import create_pandas_dataframe_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
import pandas as pd
import openai
import os


class State(rx.State):

    # The current question being asked.
    question: str

    error_texts: str

    # Keep track of the chat history as a list of (question, answer) tuples.
    chat_history: list[tuple[str, str]]

    openai_api_key: str

    # The files to show.
    csv_file: list[str]

    upload_confirmation: str = ""

    file_path: str

    is_loaded_skeleton: bool = True

    async def handle_upload(
        self, files: list[rx.UploadFile]
    ):
        """Handle the upload of file(s).

        Args:
            files: The uploaded files.
        """
        for file in files:
            upload_data = await file.read()
            outfile = rx.get_asset_path(file.filename)
            self.file_path = outfile

            # Save the file.
            with open(outfile, "wb") as file_object:
                file_object.write(upload_data)

            # Update the csv_file var.
            self.csv_file.append(file.filename)

            self.upload_confirmation = "csv file uploaded successfully, you can now interact with your data"



    def answer(self):
        # turn loading state of the skeleton component to False
        self.is_loaded_skeleton = False
        yield

       # check if csv_file is empty to return an error
        if not self.csv_file:
            self.error_texts = "ensure you upload a csv file and enter your openai api key"
            return


        if os.path.exists(self.file_path):
            df = pd.read_csv(self.file_path)
        else:
            self.error_texts = "ensure you upload a csv file"
            return
        
        openai.api_type = "azure"
        os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"] = "azure"
        os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "<OPENAI_API_VERSION>"
        os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"] = "https://<OPENAI_API_BASE>.openai.azure.com/"
        os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "<OPENAI_API_KEY>"
        
        llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4")
        
        # initializes an agent for working with a chatbot and integrates it with a Pandas DataFrame
        agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
                    llm,
                    df,
                    verbose=True,
                    agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
                )


        self.upload_confirmation = ""

        # Add to the answer as the chatbot responds.
        answer = ""
        self.chat_history.append((self.question, answer))
        yield

        # run the agent against a question
        output = agent.run(self.question)

        self.is_loaded_skeleton = True

        # Clear the question input.
        self.question = ""

        # Yield here to clear the frontend input before continuing.
        yield

        # update answer from output
        for item in output:
            answer += item
            self.chat_history[-1] = (
                self.chat_history[-1][0],
                answer,
            )
            yield
```

I've checked the endpoint, api-key and deployment name, all true. It should work but somehow it doesn't.
.......
Please help!

Comment: what version of openai, langchain, and langchain_experimental are using? sometimes they don't play too well with each other...

Comment: langchain Version: 0.0.326, openai Version: 0.28.1, langchain-experimental
Version: 0.0.36.

Comment: After upgrading all 3 to versions: langchain- 0.1.6, openai- 1.12.0, langchain-experimental- 0.0.50, still gives me an error: openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}

Comment: gotcha. downgrading to langchain-experimental==0.0.49 helped me with a potentially similar problem. if you're still getting errors after downgrading that package would recommend to file an issue e.g. on langchain's github